# HttpContext.User in Asp.net core 3.1 + Angular with OpenIDConnect and external login

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi, openid-connect, onelogin, cookie-authentication

I am using Angular + Asp.net Core 3.1 Web api which is integrated with OpenIDConnect using Cookie Authentication for the Single Sign on(OneLogin).I am not not using Identity. Angular is published on Asp.net core on IIS ( same domain). Cookie expiration is 7 hours as configured in Startup.cs. I am facing the issue where randomly(mostly bit of idle time), the following request anything to deal with HttpContext.User object takes lot of time to execute (like 42s) on production. Can anyone help?

```js
    [Route("isAuthenticated")]
        public IActionResult IsAuthenticated()
        {
            return new ObjectResult(HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
        }

       //or
       var claimsPrincial = (ClaimsPrincipal)HttpContext.User;

    //Startup.cs
    .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
          {             
              options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(420);
              options.Cookie.Name = Configuration.GetSection("CookieName").Value;              
              options.Cookie.Path = Configuration.GetSection("CookiePath").Value;              
              options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;           

          })

      services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I am facing the issue where randomly (mostly bit of idle time)

According your description, we know that most of the (non-idle) time is normal.

In IIS, you can refer below pic to let your website always on.

[image]

Comment: Jason pan - I already have the startmode as 'always runnning' and idle time out to be 1740 min. The first time its loads is very slow, and after some idle time again loads slow.

Comment: @PAR Please modify the idle time out to 0min.

Comment: Its still the same

Comment: @PAR Please use [DebugDiag tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210) to [get performance dump(choose http response times)](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/296377i6E5480B9D706B670/image-size/large?v=v2&px=999).   You can refer this doc : [Memory dumps to study a high-CPU performance issue](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/memory-dumps-to-study-a-high-cpu-performance-issue/ba-p/2556170)

Comment: Jason Pan - the prod environment where loading time is issue intermittently is aws setup iis  and sql server in separate box. Also not only after idle time sometime I hv seen just after refreshing the app it loads slow. In the  test env where iis and sql server on same box the loading time/slowless intermittently is not issue at all.  Both have same appool settimgs. Wondering what I can track to solve this issue.